Symbolic link in source using CMake
Following this question Symbolic links CMake I'm trying to set a symlink in my source code, however during the configuration the symlink never seems to be generated.
I have the current line in my CMakeLists.txt:
add_custom_target(
    SwapPerfSymlink ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E 
    create_symlink ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/noopt/file-noopt.cpp

)

Is it possible that CMake doesn't allow creating symlinks within the source files? I tried using command manually by going to the directory where the CMakeLists.txt lies and it does work (if I remove the ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ vars).

custom targets are run during build, not configuration, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html instead

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html

Thanks to both of you. The execute_process() is exactly what I needed.
Using execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/noopt/file-noopt.cpp) now creates the symlink during configuration!

@Nilau I don't mind if you create an answer showing the command you just posted in the comments and explaining that add_custom_target runs at build time. I will upvote a good answer.
